# WTForms - display property value instead of HTML field

Tags: python, forms, templates, mako, wtforms

I want to re-use a template I have with my WTForms form:

```
<th>${form.name.label}</th>
<td>${form.name()}</td>
...
```

However, on my edit page, I want the input fields to display as normal (`TextField`, `SelectField`, etc.), while on my view page, I want to just display the value of the property, not the input field with the value.

Edit page:

```
<th>Name:</th>
<td><input type="text" value="Current Name" name="name" id="name"/></td>
```

View page:

```
<th>Name:</th>
<td>Current Name</td>
```

I know I can access a field's value via `form.name.data`, but is there any way I can keep the same template with `form.name()` being called and somehow toggle whether that outputs `<input type="text"...` or `Current Name`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a custom widget:

```
from wtforms.fields import Field

class PlainTextWidget(object):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        return field.data if field.data else ''
```

Then, for my view page, I added the following:

```
form = MyForm(obj=myDataRow)
fields = [val for val in form._fields]
for fieldName in fields:
    fieldProp = getattr(form, fieldName)
    setattr(fieldProp, 'widget', PlainTextWidget())
```

Answer (score 6):

Sarah's answer above led me to the solution to a related problem: What if you want some of your fields to be read only? In that case, instead of doing run-time surgery on the form object, you could define a new `ROTextField` variant (for example), that always renders to the pure value. For example:

```
from wtforms.widgets import Input
from wtforms.fields import StringField

class TextOutput(Input):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        return kwargs.get('value', field._value())

class ROTextField(StringField):
    widget = TextOutput()
```

Now define your field with ReadOnly attributes:

```
class UserPrefs(Form):
    name     = ROTextField('name', default='Jon')
    # ...
```

Thinking about this problem helped me better understand how WTForms work. Leaving this here in case this might help someone else work through related issues.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Sarah's answer and code found in [WTForms-Components](https://wtforms-components.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#read-only-fields) I use the following to quickly turn all a form's fields into read-only and disabled fields.

Suppose we have a ProfileForm defined as follows:

```
class ProfileEditForm(Form):
    title = StringField("Title", validators=[validators.required("Please enter your title.")])
    first_name = StringField("First Name", validators=[validators.required("Please enter your first name.")])
    middle_name = StringField("Middle Name")
    last_name = StringField("Last Name", validators=[validators.required("Please enter your last name.")])
    organisation = StringField("Company Name", validators=[validators.required("Please enter your company name.")])
    organisation_website = StringField("Company Website")
    # more fields ...
```

Define the following class (based on ReadOnlyWidgetProxy from WTForms-Components):

```
class ReadOnlyAndDisabledWidgetProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.widget, name)

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('readonly', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('disabled', True)
        return self.widget(field, **kwargs)
```

Now inherit from ProfileForm as follows:

```
class ReadOnlyProfileForm(ProfileForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self._fields:
            field_property = getattr(self, field_name)
            field_property.widget = ReadOnlyAndDisabledWidgetProxy(field_property.widget)
```